# Spark structured streaming aggregation without timestamp on data (aggregation based on trigger)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I need to perform aggregation on incoming data based on spark driver timestamp, without watermark. My data doesn't have any timestamp field.

The requirement is: compute an average of the data received every sec (it doesn't matter when they have been send)

for example I need an aggregation on the data received for every trigger, just like the previous RDD streaming API.

is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own sink and do your operation on each addBatch() call:

```
class CustomSink extends Sink {
  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = {
    data.groupBy().agg(sum("age") as "sumAge").foreach(v => println(s"RESULT=$v"))
  }
}

class CustomSinkProvider extends StreamSinkProvider with DataSourceRegister {
  def createSink(
                  sqlContext: SQLContext,
                  parameters: Map[String, String],
                  partitionColumns: Seq[String],
                  outputMode: OutputMode): Sink = {
    new PersonSink()
  }

  def shortName(): String = "person"
}
```

With outputMode set to Update and a trigger every X seconds

```
  val query = ds.writeStream
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 seconds"))
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
    .format("exactlyonce.CustomSinkProvider")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "Trigger by processing time" fit your requirements?
"Trigger by processing time" triggers every interval(defined by code).

Example trigger codes are below.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/ProcessingTime.scala#L34

Comment: no, triggers just define when the aggregation is performed (its frequency) , it doesn't change the aggregation window itself

Comment: For changing windowing key, you can add processing time to your data in spark structured streaming application code.
And use processing time for windowing key.

For example, "socket" input have functions what add processing time when spark application receive from socket.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/socket.scala#L90